standard variant in tabset is not working for Community
I have a custom component for the community, inside which I'm creating a tabset. It's only displaying the first tab name; the other tab names are not being displayed. When I set the variant to "standard," it's not working, but for other variants like "scoped" or "vertical," it seems to work fine.
<template>
    <lightning-tabset heading-label="Example tabset" variant="standard">
        <lightning-tab label="Tab One" value="one">
           <c-corporategroups></c-corporategroups>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Tab Two" value="two">
            Manage Users
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Tab Three">
            Add Accounts 
        </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
</template>


When used the heading-label throws an error inside of the console for me, which is very strange considering that Salesforce's documentation example tab when I use heading-label attribute then console give error like this:Error: Unknown public property "headingLabel" of element <lightning-tabset>. This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "heading-label". Sounds like a bug to me.
